# How to escape square brackets in file paths with Invoke-WebRequest's -OutFile parameter

Tags: powershell, escaping, glob

When you include something like `[1]` in a file name like `File[1].txt` used with the `Invoke-WebRequest` and the `-OutFile` parameter you get an error `Cannot perform operation because the wildcard path File[1].txt did not resolve to a file.`

This is caused by the behavior documented [here](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3174).

With other cmdlets you would use `-LiteralPath` to force the path to be taken literally but in this case that is not an option.

I have tried escaping the `[` and `]` characters with ` or `\` but it still gives the same error.

To simplify testing you can reproduce the same issue with `Out-File`, `Test-Path`, etc.

```
#Fails
Out-File -FilePath "file[1].txt"
Out-File -FilePath "file`[1`].txt"
Out-File -FilePath "file\[1\].txt"

#Succeeds
Out-File -LiteralPath "file[1].txt"

#Fails
Test-Path -Path "file[1].txt"

#Succeeds
Test-Path -LiteralPath "file[1].txt"
```

How can I escape characters that would be used to express wildcards in `-Path`, `-FilePath`, `-OutFile`, etc. so that they function like the string was specified with `-LiteralPath` since `-LiteralPath` isn't available with `Invoke-WebRequest`?

Comment: Use single-quotes around the file and escape the square brackets with a backtick: `Test-Path -Path 'file\`[1\`].txt'`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Update**:

- In **PowerShell (Core) 7.1+**, file paths passed to the **`-OutFile`** parameter of [`Invoke-WebRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest) and [`Invoke-RestMethod`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod) are **now interpreted *literally***:

  - That is, `-OutFile` now acts like `-LiteralPath`,<sup>[1]</sup> and there is no longer a need to escape `[` and `]` characters, so that the following example command works as-is:

    ```sh
    # PowerShell 7.1+ only.
    Invoke-WebRequest http://example.org -OutFile File[1].txt
    ```
- Therefore, **the following applies only to *Windows PowerShell*** (and to now-obsolete PowerShell (Core) versions v7.0 and below):

---

*Escaping* the `[` and `]` characters as `` `[ `` and `` `] `` so that they are treated *literally* when interpreted as a *wildcard expression* with `-Path` (`-FilePath`) and `-OutFile` unfortunately only *half* works at the moment, due to a *bug* discussed in the bottom section:

- Performing the escaping ensures that the target parameter *accepts* the path (the command doesn't break anymore) ...
- ... but on *creation* of the file it is mistakenly the *escaped* representation that is used as the *literal* filename - see bottom section.

**Workaround** for now:<sup>Tip of the hat to [hashbrown](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2518317/hashbrown) for helping to simplify it.</sup>

- Make `Invoke-RestMethod` / `Invoke-WebRequest` save to a *temporary* file...
- ... and then *rename* (move) the temporary file to the desired output file path.

```sh
# Literal output file path.
$outFile = '.\file[1].txt'

# Simulate a call to Invoke-RestMethod / Invoke-WebRequest -OutFile. 
# Save to a *temporary file*, created on demand - such
# a temporary file path can be assumed to never contain '[' or ']'
'hi' |  Out-File -FilePath ($tempFile = New-TemporaryFile)

# Rename (move) the temporary file to the desired target path.
Move-Item -Force -LiteralPath $tempFile -Destination $outFile
```

<sup>In Windows PowerShell v4-, use `[IO.Path]::GetTempfileName()` in lieu of [`New-TemporaryFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/new-temporaryfile).</sup>

---

#### Escaping [literal] paths for use as wildcard patterns:

Use any of the following *string-literal* representations, which ultimately result in the same string with verbatim content  `` file`[1`].txt ``, which, when interpreted as a *wildcard expression*, is the *escaped* equivalent of literal string `file[1].txt`:

- `` 'file`[1`].txt' ``
- ``` "file``[1``].txt" ```
- ``` file``[1``].txt ```

To create this escaping *programmatically*, use:

```sh
$literalName = 'file[1].txt'
$escapedName = [WildcardPattern]::Escape($literalName) # -> 'file`[1`].txt'
```

What matters is that the target cmdlet sees the `[` and `]` as `` ` ``-escaped in the `-Path` (`-FilePath`) argument it is passed for them to be treated verbatim.

If you use `"..."` quoting or an *unquoted* argument (which mostly behaves as if it were enclosed in `"..."`), PowerShell's *string* parsing gets in the way: `` ` `` is also used as the escape character inside expandable strings (`"..."`), so in order to pass `` ` `` *through*, you must escape it itself, as ``` `` ```.

- Otherwise something like `` `[ `` inside `"..."` turns into just `[` - the `` ` `` is "eaten" - because `` `[ `` is an escaped `[` from `"..."`'s perspective, and escaping a character that doesn't need escaping turns into just that character; in short: both `` "file`[1`].txt" `` and `` file`[1`].txt `` turn into plain `file[1].txt`, as if you had never used `` ` ``.

By contrast, `` ` `` characters are used verbatim inside `'...'`-quoted strings and need no escaping.

---

#### Flawed file-creation behavior of many cmdlets with `-Path`:

The **bug** mentioned above - that on file *creation* the *escaped* representation is mistakenly used as the literal filename - **affects *most* cmdlets**, unfortunately: That is, they **unexpectedly *retain* the `` ` `` characters in the escaped pattern on *creating* a file**, so that by specifying `-Path 'file`[1`].txt'` you'll end up with a file literally named `` file`[1`].txt ``.

Fortunately, most cmdlets  *do* support `-LiteralPath`, so use of `-LiteralPath file[1].txt` is the better choice anyway and avoids this bug.

Some of the affected cmdlets:

- `Invoke-WebRequest` and `Invoke-RestMethod`
- **`Out-File`** and therefore also **redirection operators `>` and `>>`**, which effectively call `Out-File` behind the scenes.
- Note that `Set-Content` and `Add-Content` do *not* exhibit this problem.
- All(?) `Export-*` cmdlets.
- Others?

The bug has been reported in [GitHub issue #9475](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/9475).

---

<sup>[1] This was technically a breaking change, but it was considered acceptable, due to the counterintuitive nature of the original behavior. Unfortunately, the counterintuitive behavior still surfaces in many other contexts - including still with `Out-File` unless `-LiteralPath` is explicitly used. See [GitHub issue #17106](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/17106#issuecomment-1088755835) for a summary.</sup>

Comment: Your responses to this issue are very helpful.  Curious though, does any Microsoft documentation describe PowerShell's default behavior as to how square brackets are interpreted inside strings? Even more helpful would be examples of strings with file names.

Comment: Glad to hear it, @Tony. The issue boils down to whether a given target parameter supports wildcard expressions or not (where `[` is a metacharacter). In most cmdlets, it is the `-Path` parameter that supports wildcards, whereas the `-LiteralPath` parameter uses its arguments _verbatim_. Not all cmdlets observe this distinction, unfortunately, and there are several contexts in which file paths are unexpectedly treated as wildcards - see [this comment on GitHub issue #17106](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/17106#issuecomment-1088755835) for a summary.